# Track changes in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a long list of about 500.000 phone numbers, some containing spaces like **072 222 2222**.

I want to remove the spaces so that the phone number is written as **0722222222** and track changes.

I have used `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")," ","")` but now I to ensure that I track all the changes.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using excel 2013.

Comment: I have edited my answer and won't be on for a while.  If I get time I'll check back in and see if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On the 'Review' tab,  before you run your formula, click 'Track Changes' -> 'Highlight Changes', it's toward the right.

If you are creating a new column from the formula you gave you will probably just want to use conditional formatting on the new column.

To do this select the two columns, then click `Conditional Formatting` on the `Home` tab -> `Highlight Cell Rules` -> `Duplicate Values`.  This will show you numbers that have not changed which is not quite what you wanted but may be useful.

**Further Edit** When the Duplicate Values popup appears, there is a dropdown box that says "Duplicate" you can change this to "Unique" and I believe it will highlight what you want.

Comment: I can see it but that option is not available for this document. should I have my document in a particular format so that that option becomes available?

Comment: @Cand3r `Track Changes` highlights **editing** changes not the results of formulas. Conditional formatting can highlight cells that are different than the formula results. Isn't that a better answer to the question?

Comment: @creidhne OP literally says "Track Changes", twice in fact.  The way OP is doing this will require several steps to actually get what he wants.  It could be done with a macro and Tracking Changes but if he does it with a formula there is going to be another column.